# Firebird and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, firebird

Have just started converting an existing job tracking system into an ASP.NET MVC application. I'm failing miserably at getting this thing off the ground. I'm getting this error

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
```

With the following connection string

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="User ID=sysdba;Password=masterkey;Database=localhost:C:\\USINGFIREBIRD.FDB;"
     providerName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" />
```

FirebirdClient has been added to windir\assembly using gcutil

This is probably a very dumb question, but does USINGFIREBIRD.FDB have to exist? Or will it be automatically created? Regardless, with the file created it does not work.

Edit:

Ok so in the end I was having so much trouble that I decided to start fresh.

First thing I discovered was that the .NET 4 assembly cache has moved to windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly. I saw that FirebirdClient was not in here so I had to figure out how to get it in there. I used Visual studio 2010 command prompt to add the assembly with GCUTIL.

[Then I followed the information here](http://www.basarat.com/2010/02/setting-up-firebird-development-with-vs.html)

Then create a new asp.net mvc project, register your database in the server explorer, then add add an ado.net model class and have it auto generated from your database.

I'm writing this rather hastily as I'm about to leave work, hope it helps someone.

Comment: The error message talks about SQL Server, are you sure that it is actually trying to connect as Firebird, and not as SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file must exist and it must be a proper Firebird database, ie you can't just create an empty file named "USINGFIREBIRD.FDB". To create an Firebird database you can use the `isql` command line tool installed with Firebird.

BTW the error message says `The server was not found or was not accessible` - are you sure the Firebird service is running?

Comment: The file does exist, it's not just an empty file.

Comment: Well, then do you have Firebird service running? BTW what operating system and FB server version you're using? Can you connect to it with some DB managment tool?

Comment: Can connect to it with IBExpert no problem. Windows XP and firebird 2.1.3.

Comment: Then I guess it must be a connection string issue as Romias suspected... what driver do you use? If it is Firebird ADO.NET Data Provider then you should use "User" instead of "User ID" and break the DB info string into two, Database and DataSource. Try `User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=C:\USINGFIREBIRD.FDB;DataSource=localhost; Port=3050;`

Comment: Same error, but this time the innerexception, rather than being null, is '{"Keyword not supported: 'datasource'."}'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6216/discussion-between-nopygod-and-ain)

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string part "`Database=localhost:C:\\USINGFIREBIRD.FDB;`" is wrong. If you database is a file you don't need the "localhost" just the db file path.

[Here you can see valid connection strings for Firebird](http://www.connectionstrings.com/firebird).

Comment: That was one of the first things I found and I tried the connection strings but nothing helped. I just tried removing 'localhost' and still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

the file path is wrong in the string. Instead of "Database=localhost:C:\USINGFIREBIRD.FDB;" it should be: "DataSource=localhost;Database=C:\USINGFIREBIRD.FDB;"